# Fk to IK on arm is causing arm to rotate

Tags: bones, rigify, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

When I change from FK to IK on my character's arm the bicep rotates, what is causing this and how do I fix it? I think it's something to do with the bone locations in the arm but I'm not sure how to fix it if that is the issue.

[image: FK][image: IK]

Comment: I think you'll have to share your file, or a stripped-down version of it, to get a definite answer to this one, on https://blend-exchange.com/. Without it, there's too much guesswork.

Comment: @RobinBetts I have added the blend file if you are willing to look at it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just slide the IK-FK sliders, all you do is switching across modes with.

If you want to keep the pose as is, you need to use these buttons that will snap the current mode's controllers to the other:

[image]

Comment: That was part of the problem yes, I needed to get the FK>IK and IK>FK to be the same when I switched modes but I needed to apply the pose as rest pose and that fixed my issue.